# How do I concatenate string in Pentaho spoon?

Tags: business-intelligence, pentaho, kettle

I am a newbie to Pentaho (installed today). I was able to do basic transformation in Spoon. Now I need to do some stuff, which I can't figure out how.

my input looks like

```
2012-09-17|garima|fbhjgjhgj87687jghgj88jgjj|garima#1347868164626|::ffff:120.56.132.137
```

3rd field is an ID, for which I need to get some information from a REST API

```
http://api.app.com/app/api/v1/feature/fbhjgjhgj87687jghgj88jgjj
```

What do I need to do in Spoon to get this done?

Also, data return will be in json format. how do I parse that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should first get your input with a `CSV File Input` using `|` as delimiter. Then you can get the 3rd field as a string.

Next you probably need to remove all spaces from this string with a `String operations` step. Look at the `Remove special character` column, and select `space`.

Then you need to concatenate it with your http address `http://api.app.com/app/api/v1/feature/`. For this you'll use a `Calculator` step. At this step first create a new temporary field `tmpAddr`, with operation `Define a constant value for ...` (or something like this, sorry my spoon is in portuguese). At the `Field A` column you'll write your http address. It's a good practice, after you make this work, to set your address as a system variable so if it changes you don't need to replace it everywhere on your transformations (look at menu `Edit -> System Variables`).

Now on the same `Calculator` step create another field, let's say `MyAddress`, with operation `A+B`. Choose for `Field A` the field `tmpAddr` you just created, and for `Field B` the 3rd field from your input.

Now on your stream you should have the full address as a field `MyAddress`. Connect a `REST client` step. Mark `Accept URL from field` and choose field `MyAddress` as `URL Field Name`.  Set `Application Type` to `JSON`. Set `Result Fieldname` as `MyResult`.

If you need further JSON parsing you can add a `Json input` step. Set `Source is defined in a field` and select field `MyResult` as `Get Source from field`.

Comment: Great. Excellent step by step explanation and it worked like a charm :)

Answer (score 2):

An alternate approach is to use the "Replace in String" step to append the string.

1. Set 'use RegEx' to Y
2. Set 'Search' to `(.*)`
3. Set 'Replace with' to `http://api.app.com/app/api/v1/feature/$1`
4. Set 'Whole Word' to Y

The parentheses in the regex set up a capture group that you can then insert into your replacement string with the $X syntax